# Should LINQ Expressions be used inside foreach loop or not?

Tags: c#, linq

**Method 1:**

```
var list = processQueue.Where(item => item.Priority < 6);

foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Priority : {0}, Name : {1}", item.Priority, item.Name);
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
foreach (var item in processQueue.Where(item => item.Priority <6))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Priority : {0}, Name : {1}", item.Priority, item.Name);
}
```

What is the advantage of one method over another?

Comment: Worth noting that the only difference here is in expression: the compiled result will be exactly the same. There's no advantage either way in terms of performance in a built application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Are you gonna need the list in any other place other than the loop?
2. Does including the linq query in the loop statement make your code less readable?
3. (As pointed out by Dan Puzey) Do you see yourself needing to inspect the contents of `list` while debugging?

If you answered "No" to all three questions, then go ahead and make it part of the loop.

Comment: Having the separate variable can be also useful for debugging purposes (e.g. when stepping through code).

Comment: Good advice. I think `2` is likely to be answered "Yes" in most cases. For the OP's code, I think it would be more readable to do `var itemsWithPriorityLessThan6 = processQueue.Where(item => item.Priority < 6);`